# Detecting suspicious ultrasound emitters

Tags: windows, audio, security

I am looking for a program for Microsoft Windows that can give a warning whenever a program emits ultrasounds. My use case is to detect [advertisers hiding ultrasounds in their ads](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/ultrasound-tracking-could-be-used-to-deanonymize-tor-users/), so I would prefer the program to have an option to be a bit clever by judging which ultrasound looks suspicious.

Any price or license is fine.

Comment: why not just use a high-Q lowpass filter to block ultrasound altogether?

Comment: also, Tor browser bundle is based on Firefox and it has a hidden setting which disables ALL audio in browser.

Comment: The OP didn't seem to want to block ultrasound, merely to identify its source - perhaps he's building a blacklist of infringing advertisers. I'm also almost certain he wants to only block selected ultrasound, rather than silence his browser entirely.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the [SilverDog](http://ubeacsec.org/#Downloads) chrome extension could well fit your user case - at the moment it is a proof of concept that blocks ultrasonic signals from your browser by placing a audio cut off filter in the audio path.

- Licence Apache 2.0
- Price: Gratis
- [Open Source](https://github.com/mavroudisv/Silverdog/)

More details [here](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/01/06/silverdog-a-sound-firewall-for-chrome/).